Delphi serializing JSON using REST.Json vs using System.JSON.Serializers
Have just downloaded Delphi 12.1 and tried out JSON Data Binding Wizard for the first time. Amongst other options it offers
JSON mapping library: JSON marshaling/serialization library, for which the Delphi types must be generated. Options are:
   System.JSON.Serializers (using TJsonSerializer.Serialize<T> and TJsonSerializer.Deserialize<T>)
   
   REST.Json  (using TJson.JsonToObject<T> and TJson.ObjectToJsonString)

I have tried generating code using a couple of JSON examples, and from what I can tell the differences between the two libraries are:

System.JSON.Serializers supports records and JSON arrays as TObjectList
REST.Json only supports JSON arrays as TArray

Cannot find any more information about the two libraries and Delphi help often just says: Embarcadero Technologies does not currently have any additional information.
Has anybody used both approaches and can offer other reasons to pick one over the other ?

Here a brief comparison:
REST.Json:

Included in the REST.Clients library of RAD Studio.
Designed for working with REST services.
Supports basic data types, objects (with JsonSerialize attribute), and JSON arrays as TArray.
May require more manual mapping for complex data structures.

System.JSON.Serializers:

Part of the System.JSON unit in recent Delphi versions.
More general-purpose JSON serialization.
Supports records, JSON arrays as TObjectList, and most native Delphi data types.
Can be more flexible for complex data structures.
May require additional configuration for specific types.

Which one to choose:

If you're primarily working with REST services and simple data structures, REST.Json might be sufficient.
If you need more flexibility for complex data or records, System.JSON.Serializers would be a better option.

